# React Map Gl cannot find variable on production build

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I’ve made an app using React (create-react-app) and the react-map-gl library, but I do have an error in the production build, checking the logs it says

> variable x is not defined

It is a known problem and I’ve  seen a solution on GitHub, it says to downgrade the library to 5.2.1 or add  a WorkerClass but both of them doesn’t fix the error.

If I downgrade the library, it messes up some styles, whereas adding the WorkerClass doesn’t fix the issue.

How can I solve?

Comment: I believe this is the issue you are referencing https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/issues/1266. Were you able to find a viable solution?

Answer (score 0):

Edit `craco.config.js` which sits at the root of the project to tell `babel-loader` that it should ignore `mapbox-gl` from transpilation.

```js
module.exports = {
  babel: {
    loaderOptions: {
      ignore: ['./node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js'],
    },
  },
};
```

See official Mapbox GL JS documentation regarding [Excluding Mapbox GL JS explicitly from transpilation](http://Excluding%20Mapbox%20GL%20JS%20explicitly%20from%20transpilation) and Babel documentation for [`ignore`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#ignore).

Answer (score 0):

downgrade the package version to @5.2.11 and it will be ok.